# How do I use the secrets in a secretproviderclass in my mounted azure fileshare?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-secrets, fileshare

Currently, I'm mounting a fileshare in my deployments through:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /new-folder
          name: new-mount
          readOnly: true
```

and

```
      - azureFile:
          secretName: secret_name123
          shareName: sharename123
        name: new-mount
```

This worked when I save my secret_name123 file with the account name and access key of the storage account. However, I can't push account name and access key into git as they are protected information.

I tried created a secret provider class, connecting it to an azure key vault and storing the account name and access key in the key vault. I modified the file share code to look something like this:

```
      - azureFile:
          secretName: secretproviderclass123
          shareName: sharename123
        name: new-mount
```

However, it doesn't work. How can I mount my file share but have the storage account name and key be read through azure key vault?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the issue in my environment and got the below output**

I have created the ***RG & AKS cluster*** using below commands

```
az group create --name RG_Name --location eastus
az aks create -g RG_Name -n mycluster_name
```

I have created the ***key vault*** and ***secrets*** using below commands

```
    az keyvault create --location eastus --name kv_name --resource-group RG_name
   az keyvault secret set --name MYsecret_name --value "password" --vault-name KV_name
```

we have to enable or add the ***CSI drivers*** using this command

```
az aks enable-addons --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider --name Cluster_name --resource-group RG_Name
```

***We can also add the CSI drivers while creating AKS Cluster***

***Refrence for portal*:**

[image]

***Check the CSI diver is installed or not using below commands***

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

[image]

*Verify that your virtual machine scale set or availability set nodes have their own system-assigned identity, if not we have to enable it*

[image]

***I have given the identity permissions in that enable it to read the key vault and its content***

*GOTO>key vault>Access_policiies*> in

- *permissions>click on secret permissions*
- *principal>select your account*
- *application>select the application>create*

***Created the secretprovider class by using this provider class by this class will get the secrets from the key vault***

```yaml
apiVersion: v1  
kind: SecretProviderClass  
metadata:  
name: azure-kvname-system-msi  
spec:  
provider: azure  
parameters:  
usePodIdentity: "false"  
useVMManagedIdentity: "true" 
userAssignedIdentityID: "" 
keyvaultName: keyvault_name  
cloudName: "AzurePublicCloud" 
objects: |  
array:  
- |  
objectName: komali-password  
objectType: secret  
objectVersion: ""
tenantId: XXXXXXXX
```

*Apply the below command to deploy the cluster*

```
kubectl apply -f class_file_name.yaml
```

*By deploying the provider class the secrets will not be created for that we have to create the POD which will mount the volume by utilizing the CSI drivers*

```yaml
kind: Pod  
apiVersion: v1  
metadata:  
name: busybox-secrets  
spec:  
containers:  
- name: busybox  
image: busybox  
command:  
- "/bin/sleep"  
- "1000"  
volumeMounts:  
- name: XXXX  
mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"  
readOnly: true  
volumes:  
- name: XXXXX 
csi:  
driver: driver_name  
readOnly: true  
volumeAttributes:  
secretProviderClass: "class_name"
```

*Apply the below command to deploy the pod*

```
kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
```

Check the pod if it is created or not using `kubectl get pods`

[image]

*After the pod starts, the mounted content at the volume path that we specified in YAML is available*

```
kubectl exec "pod_name" -- ls /mnt/secrets-store/       
kubectl exec "pod_name" -- cat /mnt/secrets-store/"secret_name"
```